# Find node that logged an error?

Tags: ros, messages, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the title says, when a ROS error (or warning, or info) message is printed, how do I find out which node it came from?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269266/find-node-that-logged-an-error?/) by [Jacob.Beck27](https://answers.ros.org/users/31647/jacob.beck27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Programmatically or just by looking at the logging output on the console?

If the latter, configure your `ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT` to include the node name.

Related questions #q238251 and #q258929 (just to link some).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jacob.Beck27](https://answers.ros.org/users/31647/jacob.beck27/) on 2017-08-22**:
Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.